# Assign the variable values in a target's recipe in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following make file and I know it is wrong to write the following two lines in the FLAT_SRC_DIR target

```
@FLAT_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(FLAT_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
@$(OBJ_FILES) += $(patsubst $(FLAT_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$$(FLAT_SRC_FILES)))
```

How do i correct those two lines so I can use FLAT_SRC_FILES as a variable and update OBJ_FILES variable in the next line.

```
    PROJ_DIR := ../
    SRC_DIR += $(PROJ_DIR)project
    SRC_FILES += $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*/source/*.cpp)
    OBJ_DIR := $(PROJ_DIR)TASK
    OBJ_FILES += $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))

    CXXFLAGS := --c++14

    CC_INCLUDE_PATH += -I$(PROJ_DIR)project/include

    .PHONY: all clean dirs

    all: dirs $(OBJ_DIR) $(FLAT_SRC_DIR) $(OBJ_FILES) 
        "$(COMPILERBIN)"/cc.exe -rvn crackLib.a $(OBJ_FILES)

    clean:
        @rm -rf crackLib.a $(OBJ_DIR) $(FLAT_INC_DIR)  


$(FLAT_SRC_DIR):
    @echo 'Making flat source folder.'
    @mkdir -p $(FLAT_SRC_DIR)
    @OLD_CWD=$(CURDIR)
    @cd $(FLAT_SRC_DIR)
    @find  $(SRC_FILES) -name '*.cpp' | xargs -i  cp -l {} $(FLAT_SRC_DIR)
    @cd $(OLD_CWD)
    @FLAT_SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(FLAT_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
    @$(OBJ_FILES) += $(patsubst $(FLAT_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$$(FLAT_SRC_FILES)))


# Build target for directory creation. Intermediate build files will be placed here.
    $(OBJ_DIR):
        mkdir -p $@

    $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp 
        "$(COMPILERBIN)"/cc.exe $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(CC_INCLUDE_PATH) 

    $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(TSM_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
        "$(COMPILERBIN)"/cc.exe $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(CC_INCLUDE_PATH) 

    $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SL_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
        "$(COMPILERBIN)"/cc.exe $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(CC_INCLUDE_PATH) 

    -include $(OBJ_FILES:.o=.d)
```

Comment: You seem to be struggling with an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What do you actually want to do?

Comment: @Beta I want to collect, source files from different source directories and put them in one single directory and then want to build them using make.

Answer (score 1):

If that is really your goal, then here is a way to do it:

```
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(SRC_FILES)))

.PHONY: flat_source_dir
flat_source_dir:
    @for f in $(SRC_FILES); do cp $$f flat/; done
```

There are more sophisticated methods, but they can wait until you have this one working.

Comment: I have it like this now and i get an "No rule to make target"

.PHONY: all clean dirs
all: $(OBJ_DIR) $(FLAT_SRC_DIR) dirs $(OBJ_FILES) 
 "$(COMPILERBIN)"/cc.exe -rvn f360_trackerLib.a $(OBJ_FILES)

$(FLAT_SRC_DIR):
 @ echo 'Making flat source files'
 @ mkdir -p $(FLAT_SRC_DIR)
 @ OLD_CWD=$(CURDIR)
 @ cd $(FLAT_SRC_DIR)
 @ for f in $(SRC_FILES); do cp $$f $(FLAT_SRC_DIR); done
 @ cd $(OLD_CWD)
$(FLAT_SRC_DIR)/%.o: $(FLAT_SRC_DIR)/%.cpp 
 "$(COMPILERBIN)"/cc.exe"/cctc.exe $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< $(CC_INCLUDE_PATH)

-include $(OBJ_FILES:.o=.d)

Comment: OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(SRC_FILES)))

This was the key for me to move ahead. Thanks I could manage to understand and get my build now